# Defining a multidimensional field with nonstandard domain

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array `a` in Python, let's say `a=np.array([3, 4])`, and would like to define an ndarray (or something like that) of type [-3:3, -4:4], in other words, a collection x of real numbers `x[-3,-4], x[-3,-3],...,x[3,4]`, the i'th coordinate ranging over integers between -a[i] and a[i]. If the array length is given (2 in this example), I could use

`np.mgrid[-a[0]:a[0]:1.0,-a[1]:a[1]:1.0][0]`.

But what should I do if the length of a is unknown?

Comment: It's not a very good idea to name a `np.array` shape, since `shape` is an attribute of all `np.array`s.

Comment: Thx, changed to "a".

Comment: I apologize if it is a wrong question, I'm not very strong at programming and cannot solve this :(

Comment: Are you talking about doing symbolic manipulations on a grid that involves a symbolic variable? Maybe you can use SymPy, but generally speaking that's a bad idea for numeric computing and you might be better served with a computer algebra system.

Comment: @Mr. F Well, what I really need is to set up a real field indexed by n-dimensional integer vectors (with positive and negatives "coordinates") and then apply the discrete Fourier transform and process it further. It is a part of a larger python software that is being developed, but I could of course use another system...

Comment: What do you mean, of type [-3:3, -4:4] ?

Comment: @M.Massias I just tried to edit the question: I mean a collection of real numbers x[-3,-4], x[-3,-3],...,x[-3,4], x[-2,-4],...,x[3,4].

Comment: @PeterFranek see my edit when it is accepted, on how to properly format code for a readable question.

Comment: @M.Massias I appreciate it, I'm quite new here, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could generate a list of ranges with

```
[np.arange(-x,x+1) for x in a]
```

I'd have to play around with `mgrid`, or another function in `index_tricks` to figure how to use it.  I may to make it a `tuple` or pass it with a `*`.

---

`mgrid` wants slices, so this would replicate your first call

```
In [60]: np.mgrid[[slice(-x,x+1) for x in [3,4]]]
Out[60]: 
array([[[-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3],
        [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
        [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3]],

       [[-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4]]])
```

which of course can be generalized to use `a`.

My initial `arange` approach works with `meshgrid` (producing a list of arrays):

```
In [71]: np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(-x,x+1) for x in [3,4]],indexing='ij')
Out[71]: 
[array([[-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3],
        [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
        ...
        [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4]])]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. The point is just, that I cannot define `x` to be the `np.meshgrid(...)` and then assign `x[-3,-2]=something`, as he understands negative indexes as "counting from the end". So it is probably best for me to simply shift all indices to positive, as suggested by all_m...

Comment: `mgrid` and so on produce arrays that are useful for generating other values - with sums, products etc.  But the actual indexing is 'fixed' - `0...n`.  It keeps that crucial step simple and fast.  I believe `pandas` tries to give you more general indexing options.

Comment: Thank you, I see now that I can solve now my problem quite simply by reindexing to positive indices. I will just define my objects via np.zeros(...) and then assign there what I need. I didn't know that there are problems with negative indices. Regards!